# I am trying to pass some form data from one html page to another

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to pass some form data from one html page to another so this is the form from control_panel.html:

```
 <form onsubmit="return false" >
    Video URL: <input type="text" id="video_url">
    <input id="videoSRC" type="submit" value="Load Video" class="form-submit-button" >
 </form><br>
```

and this is index.html with the target element:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

in the php file I did this:

```
$url = $_GET['url'];

    echo $url;
```

and finally the javaScript file:

```
$('#videoSRC').click(function(e){

        var url = $('#video_url').val();
        $.ajax({
            url:'server.php',
            type:'GET',
            data:{url:url},
            success: function(data){
                $('index.html #container').append(data);
                console.log(data);
            }
        });

    });
```

I also want to specify that the index page is loaded in the brower, but for some reason I got no result so far, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: Jquery library is included, no errors reported , no, I am running this on localhost

Comment: you cannot access another html file element with out loading that page.

Comment: 'localhost' as in a webserver you're running locally? Or are you accessing things with the `file://` prefix? If it is the latter AJAX will not work as it makes an HTTP request requiring a web server.

Comment: yes,I am running locally

Answer (score 0):

No need to send ajax. To send value on index.html you have to pass value in URL it can be done as

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#videoSRC').click(function (e) {
            var url = $('#video_url').val();
            window.location.href = "index.html?url=" + url;
    });    
});
```

To get value from it use this function

```
var url = GetURLParameter("url");
$("#container").append(url);

function GetURLParameter(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++)
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam)
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
    return '';
}
```